# How to assign snapshot data to a label? Swift 2 & Firebase

Tags: firebase, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to create a user profile page in my app and am having trouble assigning the snapshot data to a label I created.

The data is definitely being pulled in as I can see it being printed in the log. I would like to take a specific value and assign it to a text label in the view.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import Firebase

class UserProfileVC: UIViewController {

@IBAction func editProfileButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var userBio: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var userWebSite: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var userNameFL: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var applied: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var skipped: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var matched: UILabel!

var users = [User]()
static var imageCache = NSCache()
var user: User!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    DataService.ds.CURRENT_USER_REF.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in

        print(snapshot.value)

        self.users = []

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshots {

                print("SNAP: \(snap)")

                if let userDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    let key = snap.key
                    let user = User(postKey: key, dictionary: userDict)
                    self.users.append(user)

                }
            }

        }



    })
```

Can someone please tell me how to grab data from the snapshot being printed and assign it to a given label? Here's the printout of the snapshot:

```
{
provider = password;
userName = "Ryan Bilak ";
}
SNAP: Snap (provider) password
SNAP: Snap (userName) Ryan Bilak
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to set the label text right after adding the user to your users array, your would do: `userNameFL.text = userDict["userName"]`

Comment: Thanks! I added `self.userNameFL.text = userDict['userName"] as? String` right after `self.users.append(user)` but the label still isn't updating?

Comment: This could be due to a number of things. I would check if your UILabel is correctly connected to the userNameFL property in Interface Builder, and also check if `userDict["userName"]` has the value you are expecting by simply printing it to the console with `print(userDict["userName"])`

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the delay, I did check and the UILabel is correctly connected, however when I try and print 'userDict["userName"]' it is not printing